# Manual Laplacian Pyramid Generation Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I'm having some trouble generating a laplacian pyramid in MatLab. I think I'm pretty close, but I could still use a little clarification. My main questions lies in what order to resize, blur, and then subtract the images to form the pyramid.

Here is the first version: I take the previous level of the pyramid (the original image on iteration 0), then I blur it, and then resize the both the original image and the blurry image down to .5 of their original size.

```
img = imread(file_name);
gimg = rgb2gray(img);

% Create the gaussian filter with hsize = [5 5] and sigma = 2
gaussian_filter = fspecial('gaussian',[4 4], 2);

blurred = gimg;
laplacian_img = gimg;

for i = [1 : level_number]     
    pre_blur = imresize(blurred, .5);

    blurred = imfilter(blurred, gaussian_filter, 'same');
    blurred = imresize(blurred, .5);
    laplacian_img = pre_blur - blurred;
end
```

My other solution is similar, except this time, I resize the image **before** blurring it.

```
for i = [1 : level_number]     
    pre_blur = imresize(blurred, .5);
    blurred = imfilter(pre_blur, gaussian_filter, 'same');

    laplacian_img = pre_blur - blurred;
end
```

Of the two solutions, the one that makes the most sense to me is the first. All the pictures in my textbook seem to indicate down sampling usually occurs first. That being said, all the pyramid images that I generate using the first method are **extremely** dark, and don't seem to resemble the examples in the book. The 2nd method provides much clearer images. Could anyone clarify?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?